# FOREIGN KEY SQL syntax is wrong in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, syntax-error

I am using a php script to create tables in a database. Tables 1 to 3 work perfectly, but I get this error for the rest:

> Error adding table 4:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'position(region),
>       FOREIGN KEY (illness) REFERENCES illness(name_ill) )' at line 9  Error adding table 5:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'position(region),
>       FOREIGN KEY (illness) REFERENCES illness(name_ill) )' at line 9  Error adding table 6:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'position(region),
>       FOREIGN KEY (illness) REFERENCES illness(name_ill) )' at line 10  Error adding table 7:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'position(region),
>       FOREIGN KEY (illness) REFERENCES illness(name_ill) )' at line 12

I attach the code for the tables, as I cannot find the SQL error. It seems to be a problem with the foreign key syntax, but it looks perfectly fine. I have tried adding and removing parentheses, changing the order of the foreign keys and adding a semicolon after the statement but nothing worked.

```
$table1 = "CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    passwd VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    age DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    moderator BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)";

$table2 = "CREATE TABLE position (
    region VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    x_coordinate FLOAT(24) NOT NULL,
    y_coordinate FLOAT(24) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (region)
)";

$table3 = "CREATE TABLE illness (
    name_ill VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name_ill)
)";

$table4 = "CREATE TABLE user_vaccine (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    time_vacc DATE NOT NULL,
    illness VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    region VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    usr_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (usr_id) REFERENCES user(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (region) REFERENCES position(region),
    FOREIGN KEY (illness) REFERENCES illness(name_ill)
)";

$table5 = "CREATE TABLE user_illness (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    time_ill DATE NOT NULL, 
    illness VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    region VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    usr_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (usr_id) REFERENCES user(id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (region) REFERENCES position(region),
    FOREIGN KEY (illness) REFERENCES illness(name_ill)
)";

$table6 = "CREATE TABLE official_illness (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    time_ill DATE NOT NULL, 
    illness VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    web_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    region VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    usr_id INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (usr_id) REFERENCES user(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (region) REFERENCES position(region),
    FOREIGN KEY (illness) REFERENCES illness(name_ill)
)";

$table7 = "CREATE TABLE official_vaccine (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    year_vacc SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
    perc_vacc FLOAT(4,2) NOT NULL, 
    region VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    age_group INT, 
    report_organisation VARCHAR(255), 
    usr_id INT NOT NULL, 
    illness VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (usr_id) REFERENCES user(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (region) REFERENCES position(region),
    FOREIGN KEY (illness) REFERENCES illness(name_ill)
)";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mysql there is a string function called [position()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_position), therefore `position(region)` part of the code is interpreted as a function call because of the `(region)`. This causes the syntax error.

Solution is to use the backticks to indicate that location and region are table and field names:

```
`position`(`region`)
```

You have to change this part of the code in every table.